# how to make a regular check for files after executing cmd command from java?

Tags: java, cmd

I have used the code below to run cmd commands from java (code adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java))

```
  private static void execute(File file){
   try {
        String[] command =
        {
           "cmd",
        };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        stdin.println("cd " + file.getParent());
        stdin.println("gxm -execute " + file.getPath());
        // write any other commands you want here
        stdin.close();
        int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

SyncPipe Class:

```
class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{
public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      istrm_ = istrm;
      ostrm_ = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
      try
      {
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
          {
              ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  private final OutputStream ostrm_;
  private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

this code works fine and the execution result is a file called `COMPLETED`, but i have implemented the following method to check for that file to indicate that the execution is finished.

```
  private static boolean checkFinished(String path)
{
    boolean result = false;
    String directory = path + "\\expts";
    File dir = new File(directory);
    if(dir.isDirectory())
        while(!result)
        {
            for(File f: dir.listFiles())
                if(!f.isDirectory() && "__COMPLETED__".equals(f.getName()))
                {
                    result = true;
                     break;
                }
            if(!result)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;

}
```

but when i call these methods in the main method like this:

```
           File f = new File("C:\\inputFile.txt");
    execute(f);

    System.out.println(checkFinished(f.getParent()));
```

I get the following output:

```
false // printed from the checking
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
.... // rest of cmd output
```

The problem here is that the `checkFinshed` method is printing once and print true later on when the file is already there. Whats wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

37 views and not even a comment !! Anyways, I changed my `checkFinished` method to the following and it worked. hope it will benefit someone else.

```
  private static boolean checkFinished(String path)
{
    boolean result = false;
    String directory = path + "\\expts";
    File dir = new File(directory);
    while(true) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(dir.isDirectory())
        {
            for(File f: dir.listFiles())
                if(!f.isDirectory() && "__COMPLETED__".equals(f.getName()))
                {
                    result = true;
                    logger.info(" SIMULATOR:  simulation finished ");
                     break;
                }
            if(result)
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```