# Specific Prompt command with java

Tags: java, windows, command, prompt

I would like to perform the following windows command under java :

> rmdir /s C:\Main\Second\Third
>
> Y

The problem is that there is **2 commands** to run, one for the remove and one as confirmation (a simple "Y", as you can see).

I know it's feasable but I didn't manage to make it.

```
        String rmCommand = "cmd.exe /c rmdir /s /q C:\\Main\\Second\\Third";
        
        Runtime runt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runt.exec(rmCommand);
```

So my question is : How to run these 2 above commands in prompt thanks to JAVA code.

EDIT : I modified a bit the initial code according to some proposals but it still doesn't work ... I don't know what to do.

Comment: By the way you can easily delete the files/directories with only java.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. I tried with delete but I arrived on this kind of bug : http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4722539 :/ so I think it's the only solution for me.

Comment: Have to agree with @MatjazMuhic. Why shell out for this?

Comment: Read my previous link and answer please.

Comment: If you cannot delete the file because it is locked, then rmdir won't work either, no?

Comment: and how exactly does the bug affects you?

Comment: Possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java

Comment: rmdir will work I tried "by hand". You can see the problem on this report file quoted above :( . Anyway prompt solution will be for me enough

Comment: Did you try `echo y | cmd.exe /c rmdir /s /q C:\\Main\\Second\\Third`

Answer (score 3):

`rmdir` isn't a program - it's part of the command shell. So you need to run something like:

```
"cmd.exe /c rmdir /s C:\\Main\\Second\\Third"
```

(For a production version, you'd want to make sure you got the right cmd.exe, of course.)

Comment: I see, thank you for your fast answer. But question : What if the cmd.exe ask for a confirmation ? Here I need to put "Y" in cmd to confirm the delete.

Comment: @user1618814 It is better to add this details in your question to make it more clearly

Comment: @ Alex k : As written : "So my question is : How to run these 2 above commands in prompt thanks to JAVA code."I also edited my post, sorry if it wasn't clear enough

Comment: You can use /q to not make it ask, I think.

Comment: I don't see where could be my mistake. A file F1 = new File("BLABLA") has not to be closed, isn't it ?

Comment: Does not have to be your program that locked the file, can be anything on your system.

Comment: @user1618814: You talk about two "commands" - but Y isn't a command. And as Thilo said, you should be able to use `/q` to avoid the prompt. If you can't delete the file, that's a *completely* different problem.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid being asked for confirmation, add /Q to your rmdir command: http://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm

But it is a very bad practice to do it with rmdir. If you don't want to do the recusrsive deletion stuff yourself, use [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29). And it's not the question of rmdir being enough or not, it's the question of using the tool you have the right way. If I understand you correctly, the problem you have is that java cannot delete open files, but rmdir does. Seems more like a problem with your code leaving files open, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are probably right about openned files but it's hard for me to check the whole code. I need to check the 400 lines again, I don't see where I could have forgot that ..

Comment: By the way I tried with rmdir and your proposal, no errors, but nothing deleted :/

Comment: did you run it with cmd.exe, as Jon Skeet answered?

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the question about whether its good practice or not, the answer to your question is as follows: create a file containing the single character `Y`. Let's say its called `y.txt`.

Then your command would be:

```
cmd.exe /c rmdir /s C:\\Main\\Second\\Third < y.txt
```