# Taskkill : to close a java program

Tags: java, cmd, dos

I supposed to close a process (java). This process is invoked by a batch file.
The batch file title is 
    "Secondary Push"

When i double the batch file, it opens a command prompt and records the log.

-How to close the java process ??
-How to get the process id of the particular java process... using command prompt. Not by Task Manager.

Comment: Which version of ms-dos does java run on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tasklist` will show you the details.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "underline="
SET "mypid="
FOR /f "skip=2delims=" %%u IN ('tasklist/v') DO IF NOT DEFINED underline SET underline=%%u
FOR /f "delims=" %%u IN ('tasklist/v^|find /i "GPU Client"') DO IF NOT DEFINED mypid SET mypid=%%u
:loop
IF "%underline:~0,1%"=="=" SET underline=%underline:~1%&SET mypid=%mypid:~1%&GOTO loop
FOR %%u IN (%mypid%) DO IF DEFINED underline SET mypid=%%u&SET "underline="
echo Target process ID=%mypid%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should get the process ID ready for `TASKKILL`. The string `GPU Client` should be replaced by a uniwue string identifying the java process that you wish to terminate, which you should be able to derive from a `tasklist` listing from the prompt.

```
 tasklist /v
```

The length of the underline appearing under the `tasklist /v` report heading varies depending on the length of the longest name of tasks currently running, so the underline line is applied to `underline`, the selected detail line to `mypid` and then the first character of each string is trimmed off until the space in the line-of-`=` is found.

At this time, `mypid` will have the taskname trimmed off, so its first token is the PID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) and [Taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx).

Comment: Can anyone provide batch script, which identify the process java-process and kill that process. Because i need to do it programatically

Comment: You can [execute cmd commands in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java).

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /im java*
```

should kill the Java processes.

Comment: this will impact the other java programs that are running