# Execute commands in irb from java

Tags: java, ruby, shell, terminal, irb

I want to start irb (Interactive Ruby Shell) in terminal using java and then execute different commands on that already opened irb shell when particular event occurs.
  I have tried `Runtime.exec()` method but it executes commands on terminal or command prompt only and is unable to execute commands in irb shell. Also every time it executes commands on new instance of terminal instead of same instance. I want to execute multiple commands on same terminal instance instead of newly created instance of terminal.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you written? We need to see how you're doing it.

Comment: you should be able to open irb then write via outputstream to it...how are you getting multiple console windows are you executing irb several times? I suppose another way would be to embed jruby and execute that...

Comment: Thanks rogerdpack. I have used outputstream given by process to write and execute commands. I used solution provided at following link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5437863/2141218

Comment: I am stuck in mac for doing the same thing. I have tried following code :

{String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-k", "cd", "/Users/userName/Documents"};
Runtime.exec(cmd); }

and 

{String[] cmd = {"open", "-a", "terminal.app"};
Runtime.exec(cmd); }

but no luck.Please help...