# Copy video from my own machine to EC2 server by running scp command (JSCH)

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jsch

I need to SCP a video file from my local machine to a EC2 cloud server using a Java program. I am using the JSCH library to do so.

So far I can connect to the EC2 server and can run basic commands on it. Following is the code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EC2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, IOException,     InterruptedException 
    {
        JSch jsch=new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity("yyyy.pem");
        jsch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        //enter your own EC2 instance IP here
        Session session=jsch.getSession("ec2-user", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 22);
        session.connect();

        //run stuff
        String command = "whoami;hostname";
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.connect();


        InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
        //start reading the input from the executed commands on the shell
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) 
        {
            while (input.available() > 0) 
            {
                int i = input.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isClosed())
            {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Now I am aware of the SCP syntax for file transfer . But the thing here is that every command that I now here will be run the EC2 server
For eg: String command = "ls -l"; Will give me the home file list in the EC2.

So how do I transfer the video stored on my laptop the home/ec2-user directory of the EC2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `scp` command must be run locally and not on the EC2 Instance.  No need of JSCH library for that.  See this question for more details [How to execute cmd commands via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java)

Of course, `scp` must be locally available too ....

--Seb

Comment: Yes, but I need to do a performance test of EC2, so I will eventually push 1000's of videos into it. Hence I am writing a JAVA program to do so.

Comment: Sometime a simple shell script is much easier to develop than a Java application.  If you have to push a large quantity of data to AWS for processing on an EC2 instance, I would suggest to have a look at S3.  Your local machine can upload to s3 (using the CLI or a Java program) and your EC2 program download from S3 before processing the file.