# Get Build Windows version with Java

Tags: java, windows, build, compilation

if you run with CLI (or CMD) the command "winver" you obtain build version...

Compilation.

Is it possible obtain the build (compilation) version of Windows with Java?

**EDIT**
Running winver open popup windows, I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command "`SYSTEMINFO`" in command prompt.

You will followed by these details

```
Host Name:                 SOMENAME
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          SOMENAME
Registered Organization:   SOMENAME
Product ID:                55041-007-1931133-86361
Original Install Date:     3/11/2014, 9:41:37 AM
System Boot Time:          4/15/2014, 5:25:18 PM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              OptiPlex 3010
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9 GenuineInt
```

Comment: the problem with CMD & systeminfo is depends of Language of OS.. the result in english is different to spanish, francaise, italian... etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the CMD command from JAVA and obtain the resultif you do not prefer the other method.  Please have a look at this: [How to execute cmd commands via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java)