# Inputting a command to cmd with Java

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to make a Java script where the user can type a command from the Java console in Eclipse, and the command will be sent to the cmd.  For example, when you run the program, the console will ask the user what command they want to use, and the command they put in will be sent to the cmd.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java --> Get the command user typed.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java --> Launch cmd commands in java.

Comment: I am stuck on the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console console = System.console();
String com = console.readLine("Enter command:");
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(com);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Scanner` ( [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)  ) to get the command

Then use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` to execute it

Comment: What I was thinking is if someone would type a command in the Eclipse console, and the command would be sent to the cmd.  Thanks for the help!