# Java application run in Terminal shell?

Tags: java, windows, macos, command-prompt

In Java, how would I use a command line shell like **cliche** ([can be found here](https://code.google.com/p/cliche/)) and launch it using an actual system command prompt shell? In my case "Terminal" for OSX.

I am trying to use it as the interface for my java application.

**For example:**

When the user types "hello" into the command prompt, the java application would print "Hello world".

Comment: What exactly maps the input 'hello' back to 'Hello World'?  Are you saying that you just want to have your program be runnable on the command line?  Because if thats what your saying, you don't really have to do anything.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by runnable. I know you can launch Jar files using "java -jar EXAMPLE.jar". If you mean, do I want to have my java application run through command line and process/send input/output through it, then yes.

Comment: send input and output to where?  the shell?

Comment: thank you for your help :) i appreciate your time. And yes I want the user to be able to send commands through the shell, and the java application to print to the shell.

Comment: then JSch is the answer - or you can use a ProcessBuilder and do Runtime.exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch) to connect to your local or remote `sshd` server and access the shell.  There are many [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) you can look at.

> I am trying to use it as the interface for my java application.

That doesn't make sense - could you elaborate?

**EDIT**: Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java) answer for an example of using Runtime.exec to possibly achieve what you want.

Comment: mmm that's a bit overboard, why do I need an sshd server just to have a command prompt as menu for a local Java application.

Comment: I've added an example to the question

Comment: I didn't realize i could use the Runtime.exec for this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example, we have a Java file named *Hello.java* saved in document *HelloWorld* in *Documents* directory.
Open terminal and type in `$ cd Documents/HelloWorld` Than type in command `javac Hello.java`. This command will compile *Hello.java* document and a file with a coffee sign next to it, named *Hello* should appear. After this, type to terminal command `java Hello`. This will launch the compiled file and down below should appear the text you wanted to be written