# Create a childprocess and make it run a function or class method

Tags: java, process

I come from a very `C` background and am totally new to Java. What I want to do is something like [`fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) in C. I have looked at `ProcessBuilder`, but all examples seem to spawn an external process as in the following example:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/chmod", "777", path).start();
p.waitFor();
```

I want the new child process to start executing a new function, or a class method.

What I want to do should behave something like:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(<CLASS_METHOD>).start();
p.waitFor();
```

The parent process executes the next line (the line containing `waitFor()`) where as the child process begins executing the given `<CLASS_METHOD>`.

How can I get this done?

**Additional question:** Is there any way I can get a handler to `SIGCHLD`? I want to create a new child-process when one of the child processes die.

Comment: Look into threads or the Java concurrency API.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I do not want threads. I want separate processes.

Comment: Possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319804/adapting-c-fork-code-to-a-java-program

Comment: That again runs a command

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just create a new java process using the process builder? Something like following.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/java /tmp/Main.class").start();
p.waitFor();
```

if you don't want to hard code the class path, you can do the following to get the path.

```
String path = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Comment: My question is - I do not want to run a command via a string. I want the control to go to a function or block of code for the child process.

Comment: FTR: Upvoted. It seems there's no solution other than via command. Thanks.