# Execute multiple commands in command line using Java

Tags: java, macos, terminal, communication, reader

I'm working on a chess program in Java. To calculate the best move (when a person plays against the computer) I use a UCI (universal chess interface). That's a Terminal application (I'm using Mac OS X). With Java I want to execute some commands to get the best move. That's what I have up to now:

```
String[] commands = {"/Users/dejoridavid/Desktop/stockfish-6-64", "isready", "uci"};
Process process = null;
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

// read the output from the command
String s;
try {
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The first command in the array calls the terminal application. The second and third one are both in-app-commands. Now I have one problem. Only the first two commands are executed, their result is printed in the console, the third command is ignored. Did I do something wrong? Please tell me how to also execute the third (or more, 4th, 5th, etc) command.

Comment: Is it always the third command? Have you tried other commands? Maybe have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5437863/1638708), don't know if it helps

Comment: As an aside, if you are using this approach it is worth reading the following in case you find yourself getting hard to track bugs: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute commands inside another program.
The array you pass to the exec method take the first element of the array as the command and the others as parameters for the command.

From javadoc of public `Process exec(String[] cmdarray) throws IOException`

> Parameters: cmdarray - array containing the command to call **and its
>   arguments.**

You have to execute the main command with a call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

Then you have to write/read the commands /answers using the inputstream/outputstream of the `Process` returned by the call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

To retrieve inputstream and outputstream of a process use the `getInputStream()`  and `getOutputStream()` methods on the process object

Comment: Can you post some code, an example, which shows how i should approach this?

Comment: You can find an example using a bash shell here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Comment: If you find this answer useful and correct you can flag it with the green check and upvote. Thank you