# How to fetch java installation path

Tags: java

I am creating one bat file, like `internet.bat`.

This is my bat file data.

```
    set class = java instalation path in my local    
    java AddTrustedSite

    java DisablePopup 

pause
```

Now I want to fetch java installation path dynamically using java in my local.

Comment: And why do you want that? Isn't that enough that you can run your programs?

Comment: this is my requirement.If any one run this bat file along with my java files(AddTrustedSite,DisablePopup ) it should be run.

Comment: Trouble is that a system can easily have multiple Java runtimes installed. There is no "the java installation path" to speak of.

Comment: better to rely on environment variable `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command in Windows,

where java

Comment: "where java" I guess .. 
C:\Users\user>where javac
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Users\user>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe

Comment: Btw @jyothi for running command line commands through java look eg. there (maybe you will find something better) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java