# Clear screen - Why wont Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls") work? (Java)

Tags: java, console

I had already searched about clearing the screen in java console, and some suggest to use

```html
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

to clear the screen, but it doesn't clear it at all. It just gives a runtime error

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cls": CreateProcess error=2
```

Can somebody please explain why it isn't working (and yes, I'm in windows).
Please dont suggest things like "you shouldnt clear screen" or suggest another way of clearing the screen,
I just want to know why this code will give me an error, despite that I'm in Windows.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `cls` is a command that is processed by `cmd` or `command` (a *shell* command), not a program.

Comment: Why do some users suggest this way of clearing the screen, if it doesn't work anyway? Is there something I missed, in order for this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute cmd commands via Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java)

Comment: @Imaginate You want to clear Eclipse's screen?

Comment: yeah im using eclipse, but an IDE independent solution would be better (I'm exporting it to a jar)

Comment: @Imaginate what screen you want to clear ?

Comment: Idrk what exactly handles the program, but Im wrapping the jar in an exe, so all the printing is in the console that starts up when i run the exe

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379766/9092024) explains everything, and provides an alternative.