# How to use Maven to encrypt a password — from Java?

Tags: java, maven, maven-invoker-plugin

I want to encrypt a password with maven, from within a Java program. Basically, I want to achieve the equivalent of calling `mvn --encrypt-password p4ssw0rd`, but without dropping to the command line.

I've looked into [Apache Maven Invoker](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html). I've found setters on [`InvocationRequest`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/InvocationRequest.html) for _some command line options, such as `InvocationRequest.setShowVersion(..)` for `--show-version`. But I can't find one for `--encrypt-password`.

Is there a way to do this, either with Apache Maven Invoker or another way? I do not want to [drop to or call a command line directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157303/2936460), since I want to be platform independent.

**How do I invoke `mvn --encrypt-password p4ssw0rd` from a Java program?**

---

Comment: @DamCx, no I want the equivalent of that. I want the same result. I've edited my question to reflect that better.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use the plexus-cipher library, which is apparently what Maven uses to do the encryption.

See the code at https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-cipher

The unit tests will probably be enut to get you started.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll look into that.